# Angular2: issues the barcode function is undefined

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am fresher in angular 2, I am developing an ionic 2 app in that i am using bar-code scanner plugin, the problem is I am scanning the bar-code depending on the number of orders, but unfortunately I'm getting an error showing below

error.log

```
**EXCEPTION: Error in ./AcceptOrdersFromVanPage class AcceptOrdersFromVanPage - inline template:64:8 caused by: this.barcode(...) is undefined  main.js:64726:9
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: this.barcode(...) is undefined  main.js:64728:13
ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:  main.js:64731:13
AcceptOrdersFromVanPage/this.vendorbarcode@http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:26913:17
AcceptOrdersFromVanPage</AcceptOrdersFromVanPage.prototype.AcceptOrderfromVendor@http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:27016:9
anonymous/View_AcceptOrdersFromVanPage2.prototype.handleEvent_14@/AppModule/AcceptOrdersFromVanPage/component.ngfactory.js:428:21
DebugAppView</DebugAppView.prototype.eventHandler/<@http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:127682:24
decoratePreventDefault/<@http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:46755:36
O</d</t.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:9712
onInvokeTask@http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:44826:28
O</d</t.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:9640
O</v</e.prototype.runTask@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:7064
t/this.invoke@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:10834
EventListener.handleEvent*u@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:2:27976
O</d</t.prototype.scheduleTask@http://localhost:8100/build/poly[…]  main.js:64732:13
ERROR CONTEXT:  main.js:64735:13
Object { _view: Object, _nodeIndex: 14, _tplRow: 64, _tplCol: 8 }  main.js:647**
```

this is my template.html

```
<ion-content>
  <div *ngIf="torders">
  <ion-card *ngFor='let d of torders; let i = index;'>
    <ion-card-header>
      <p><strong>Total Order(s) : </strong>{{d.Total_Orders}}</p>
    </ion-card-header>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button icon-left clear small (click)="Accept(i, torders)">
          Accept
        </button>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-card>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

and this my .ts file

```
export class AcceptPage implements OnInit {
 bartxt: any;
  orderids: any;
  orderarray: any;
  orderstring: any;
  totalorders: any;
  _i: number = 0;
barcode(index, torders) {
    BarcodeScanner.scan().then((barcodeData) => {
      if (barcodeData.cancelled) {
        alert("User cancelled the action!");
        return false;
      }
      this.bartxt = barcodeData.text;
      if (this.bartxt != '') {
        this.authservice.validate(this.bartxt, this.orderids)
          .subscribe(data => {
            if (data == "BARCODE_FOUND") {
               alert("scanned successfully");
                if (this._i == (this.totalorders - 1)) {
                  this._i = 0;
                  this.finalacceptvendor(index, torders);
                } else {
                  this._i++;
                  this.vendorbarcode(index, torders);
                }
            } else {
              alert("wrong qr code")
              this.vendorbarcode(index, torders);
            }
          });
      }
    });
  }

public vendorbarcode = function (index, torders) {
    this.totalorders = this.torders[index].Total_Orders;
    this.orderarray = this.orderstring.split(',');
    this.orderids = this.orderarray[this._i];
    while (this._i < this.totalorders) {
      this.barcode(index, torders)
        .then(function (response) {
        });
    }
  }
Accept(index, torders) {
    this.vendorbarcode(index, torders);
  }

finalacceptvendor(index, torders) {
    this.authservice.finalFunction(this.torders[index].OrderId)
      .subscribe(data => {
        if (data == 'UPDATE_SUCCESS') {
          alert("success");
        } else {
          alert("fail");
        }
      },
      err => {
        console.log('err');
      });
  }
}
```

I have gone through some posts related to my problem but unable to sort the issue.. Please help me sort this issue...

Comment: are you getting any ts lint errors ? I predict you will be getting

Comment: I'm getting the above mentioned error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not returning from your `barcode()` method so you should be using as

```
barcode(index, torders) : Promise<any> { ///////////////
   return BarcodeScanner.scan().then((barcodeData) => {
      if (barcodeData.cancelled) {
        alert("User cancelled the action!");
        //return false;//////////remove this line
      }
      this.bartxt = barcodeData.text;
      if (this.bartxt != '') {
        this.authservice.validate(this.bartxt, this.orderids)
          .subscribe(data => {
            if (data == "BARCODE_FOUND") {
               alert("scanned successfully");
                if (this._i == (this.totalorders - 1)) {
                  this._i = 0;
                  this.finalacceptvendor(index, torders); 
                } else {
                  this._i++;
                  this.vendorbarcode(index, torders);    
                }
            } else {
              alert("wrong qr code")
              this.vendorbarcode(index, torders); 
            }
          });
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: I edited as you suggested but showing this error [ts] A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value.

Comment: Check my updated answer. also lemme know if you are available in **team viewer** I can fix it for you

Comment: [ts] Generic type 'Promise<T>' requires 1 type argument(s)

Comment: the conversation will continue on and on. are you available in team viewer?

Comment: i am available in team viewer

Comment: reach me out in fb @ aravind2109. also i sent you msg. share the credentials there

Answer (score 0):

`barcode`  method should return a promise if `vendorbarcode` method is trying to do `this.barcode(index, torders).then(...)`